# Convert an IplImage to SDL_Surface with single nChannals

Tags: c, opencv, sdl, sdl-2, iplimage

How to convert an IpLImage to SDL_Surface.

I used this [`post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393954/how-to-convert-an-opencv-iplimage-to-an-sdl-surface)to convert an image with 8 nChannels and it worked perfectly, but when I try this with an image of a single nChannel it displays the following message on the console:

```
 Depth 8, nChannels 1, pitch 640
 Unable to convert the IplImage image ! SDL Error: Unknown pixel format
```

And this is the code I used :

```
int pitch = colored_capture->nChannels * colored_capture->width;
printf("Depth %d, nChannels %d, pitch %d\n", colored_capture->depth,
                colored_capture->nChannels, pitch);

surface_1 = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom((void*)colored_capture->imageData,
                       colored_capture->width,
                       colored_capture->height,
                       colored_capture->depth * colored_capture->nChannels,
                       colored_capture->widthStep,
                       0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0xff0000, 0);

if (surface_1 == NULL)
{
   fprintf ( stderr ,"Unable to convert the IplImage image ! SDL 
Error: %s \n", SDL_GetError());
}
```

Comment: If it is only 8 bits per pixel, why masks describe it as 24 bit? What is your source data? Is it grayscale? Indexed? In what format do you want to get your resulting surface?

Comment: I applied the `CannyEdgeFilter` on a image captured by a camera and when I tried to convert it to `SDL_Surface` with the code appove, it didn't work.

Comment: ..which creates grayscale image, as I had to google just now. Still no indication of what you need SDL surface for, and what format should it have. If you really don't care (can't imagine why), take a look at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27204397/greyscale-image-in-sdl2

Comment: well, I need to visualize two images, the original one and another that I will apply some CV processing on it, and all that using only low-level library, that why I chose SDL. For the format, I think it doesn't matter cuz all I do is visualization.

Comment: @keltar what do you think about using Gtk instead of SDL ?

Comment: SDL is simplier if you need to display custom image data. Have you tried setting palette as specified in a link to another question? Your initial problem is that your image is grayscale and SDL thinks 8 (or 4) bits per pixel is paletted image. Other method would be duplicating grayscale data to each channel (the same in R, G, and B).

Comment: Actually, I'm not quite familiar with these concepts, although I tried as you suggested in a previous comment, but It didn't work.